# Аккаунт разработчика из Украины в Google Play(Android Market) для продажи приложений

Tags: android, google-play

Подскажите,каким образом можно зарегистрироваться в `Google Play(Android Market)` чтобы продавать свои приложения?
На данный момент Украины нет в списке стран,которым разрешено продавать,можно лишь публиковать бесплатные приложения,но читал,что можно каким то образом обойти это ограничение,например писать страну Россия,регион Украина и далее...
В связи с этим у меня и вопросы:

1. Для этого лучше регистрировать новый аккаунт или можно использовать свой основной,но подредактировать страну проживания и что лучше - новый акк или свой основной?
2. Нужно привязать расчетный счет,для вывода денег от продаж,так вот - достаточно ли иметь карту `Payoneer` и собственно как привязать карту к `Google Wallet`?
   В общем интересуют подробности,как зарегистрироваться находясь в Украине не выезжая из нее.

У кого есть подобный опыт,на что надо обратить внимание?
Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 3):

Почему вы против паблишеров? Не все жулики, есть и нормальные компании, которые сами разрабатывают приложения и предоставляют услуги по публикации другим разработчикам из стран, в которых не доступен вывод средств из `Google Play` (Украина, Беларусь и др.). Знаю таких.

Решение, на сегодняшний день, публиковаться через издателя, является разумным и официальным, правда,  можно еще самому открыть фирму в другой стране и зарегистрироваться как разработчик, но это стоит денег и много волокиты...

Answer (score 2):

Используйте модель продаж [Adware](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware) - если вкратце то в прогу встраиваете некий плейсхолдер куда рекламодатель может поместить свою рекламу и вам платят за каждый клик юзера. Таких платформ много (я бы даже сказал очень много) - у каждого свой немудреный API/SDK.

Я, в период, когда в России нельзя было брать бабки за прогу использовал [Smaato](http://www.smaato.com). Денежки - пусть и небольшие капают до сих пор.

В сети есть множество жуликов предлагающих от своего имени выставить прогу на соответствующем маркете - не ведитесь на них - я знаю массу случаев когда обманывали.

Comment: меня интересует возможность продажи приложений на маркете,вопрос не в монетизации приложения а продаже,то есть заработок не от рекламы а от продажи